# Increment counter when button is clicked in different languages

Tags: android, xml

Whenever i click on button increment/decrement operation is done and it displays count in english. But instead of displaying counts in English suppose i want to display it in other languages like Hindi, French etc but not i English. To achieve that what should i do? String resources ? And how?

Thank you

This is my increment method which works fine but increments only in English language and i want to support other language as well

```
public void incrementDosa(View view) {

        if (QuantityDosa == 10) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.maxOrder, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        QuantityDosa = QuantityDosa + 1;
        TextView dis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Dosa_Quant);
        dis.setText("" + QuantityDosa);       

}
```

Comment: What you did till now? Show your code.

Comment: This is my increment method which works fine but increments only in English language and i want to support other language as well

public void incrementDosa(View view) {

        if (QuantityDosa == 10) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Maximum Order Reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        QuantityDosa = QuantityDosa + 1;
        TextView dis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Dosa_Quant);
        dis.setText("" + QuantityDosa);       

}

Comment: I think this link should help https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#FormatNumbers

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I understood.

In your `res/values/strings.xml`, add this :

```
<string name="toast_text">Maximum Order Reached</string>
```

In your `res/values-hi/strings.xml`, add this :

```
<string name="toast_text">अधिकतम आदेश पहुंचे</string>
```

And the code :

```
public void incrementDosa(View view) {

    if (QuantityDosa == 10) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    QuantityDosa = QuantityDosa + 1;
    TextView dis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Dosa_Quant);
    dis.setText(String.format("%d", QuantityDosa));  
}
```

Hindi device :

[image: Hindi]

English device :

[image: EN device]

> Suppose that your application's default language is English. Suppose
>   also that you want to localize all the text in your application to
>   French, and most of the text in your application (everything except
>   the application's title) to Japanese. In this case, you could create
>   three alternative strings.xml files, each stored in a locale-specific
>   resource directory:
>
> 1.res/values/strings.xml
>
> Contains English text for all the strings that the application uses,
>   including text for a string named title.
>
> 2.res/values-fr/strings.xml
>
> Contain French text for all the strings, including title.
>
> 3.res/values-ja/strings.xml
>
> Contain Japanese text for all the strings except title.
>
> If your Java-based code refers to R.string.title, here is what happens
>   at runtime:
>
> If the device is set to any language other than French, Android loads
>   title from the res/values/strings.xml file. If the device is set to
>   French, Android loads title from the res/values-fr/strings.xml file.
>   Notice that if the device is set to Japanese, Android looks for title
>   in the res/values-ja/strings.xml file. But because no such string is
>   included in that file, Android falls back to the default, and loads
>   title in English from the res/values/strings.xml file.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Edit : thanks to @Akshay for the comment

Comment: I have done with adding resources that is res/values-hi/strings.xml file to support Hindi language and also everything is works fine except  that when i click on increment button, it display count in English and not in Hindi @Thomas Mary

Comment: Yes, I have done with adding toast and it is also working as expected. Only problem is when i click on increment button it is displaying 0,1,2,3,.....,10 (In English) and what i want is ०,१,२,३,४,५,.....,१० (In Hindi) @Thomas Mary

Comment: Try `NumberFormat.getInstance().format(QuantityDosa);`

Comment: You can try : `String.format("%d", QuantityDosa)` to display. It will take care about phone locale. @user9303364

Comment: Failed to print in Hindi @Thomas Mary

Comment: `String.format("%d", QuantityDosa)` is perfectly working in Hindi, see pictures. What do you mean by 'failed to print' ?

Comment: I mean i tried both i.e `NumberFormat.getInstance().format(QuantityDosa);` and `String.format("%d", QuantityDosa)` but none of them works @Thomas Mary